# Subtracting the last elements in each row of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

There are two lists:

```
list1 = {{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {2, 5, 7}};
list2 = {{1, 2, 7}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 5, 6}};
```

How can we subtract the last number of each row in `list2` from `list1` as

```
diff = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, -2}, {2, 5, -1}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
diff = list1;
diff[[All, -1]] = Subtract[list2[[All, -1]], list1[[All, -1]]];
diff
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, -2}, {2, 5, -1}}

```
diff2 = list2;
diff2[[All, -1]] -= list1[[All, -1]];
diff2
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, -2}, {2, 5, -1}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
list1 // ReplacePart[ {i_, 3} :> Differences[ {list1, list2}, {1, 0} ][[ 1, i, 3]] ]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, -2}, {2, 5, -1}}

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {2, 5, 7}};

b = {{1, 2, 7}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 5, 6}};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[Last /@ (b - a) &, a, {All, -1}]
```

{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, -2}, {2, 5, -1}}

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Transpose[
 Append[Transpose[list1 ][[1 ;; 2]], 
  Last[Transpose[list2 ] - Transpose[list1 ]]]]

(*  {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, -2}, {2, 5, -1}}   *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = {{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {2, 5, 7}};
l2 = {{1, 2, 7}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 5, 6}};
```

Using `Thread` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
rep = s_?VectorQ :> If[DuplicateFreeQ[s], Subtract @@ s, s[[1]]];

Thread /@ Thread[{l2, l1}] /. rep

(*{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, -2}, {2, 5, -1}}*)
```

Or using `Map` and `Thread`:

```
Map[x |-> {Splice@Most@x[[1]], x[[1, 3]] - x[[2, 3]]}, Thread[{l2, l1}]]

(*{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, -2}, {2, 5, -1}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `MapThread`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list1 = {{1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {2, 5, 7}};
list2 = {{1, 2, 7}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 5, 6}};

MapThread[Most@#1~Join~{Last@#2 - Last@#1} &, {list1, list2}]
```

or

```
MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #2[[3]] - #1[[3]]} &, {list1, list2}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, -2}, {2, 5, -1}}